# definition column from sys.check_constraints is coming as null in ado.net datareader when the field is not null when executed from sssms

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to write a C# program (.Net core 2.1) to read all the check constraints for a given table from ms sql server database. I am using sys.check_constraints table to get this information, when I tried to read this using ado.net datareader the column 'definition' from this table is always coming as empty though it has value.

SQL Script (DDL, Stored Proc to Get CheckConstraints, Exec state of Stored Proc)

```
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 7/10/2019 3:24:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Prefix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Suffix] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [NickName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ProfilePictureName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfDeath] [date] NULL,
    [Gender] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Process] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [MessageId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SysStartDate] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SysEndDate] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [CompanyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartDate], [SysEndDate])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_601769201] )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [IsActive]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_PREFIX_CHECK] CHECK  (([Prefix]='Dr' OR [Prefix]='Miss' OR [Prefix]='Ms' OR [Prefix]='Mrs' OR [Prefix]='Mr'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_PREFIX_CHECK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_SUFFIX_CHECK] CHECK  (([Suffix]='RN' OR [Suffix]='MD' OR [Suffix]='ESQ' OR [Suffix]='DO' OR [Suffix]='DDS' OR [Suffix]='DDM' OR [Suffix]='III' OR [Suffix]='II' OR [Suffix]='I' OR [Suffix]='Sr' OR [Suffix]='Jr'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_SUFFIX_CHECK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_TYPE_CHECK] CHECK  (([Type]='Customer' OR [Type]='VENDOR' OR [Type]='INSIDER' OR [Type]='ANALYST' OR [Type]='INVESTOR'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_TYPE_CHECK]
GO




CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCheckConstraints_Dup](@tableName as varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
select 
    col.[name] as column_name,
    con.[definition] As [constraint_value]
from sys.check_constraints con
    left outer join sys.objects t
        on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    left outer join sys.all_columns col
        on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
where t.[name]=@tableName and con.is_disabled=0
order by con.name;
End;

GO

exec GetCheckConstraints_Dup 'Customer'
```

[SQL Server Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RNSu.png)

C#

```
        public static List<Constraints> GetConstraints(string tableName,string connectionString)
        {
            var constraints = new List<Constraints>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //SqlDataReader
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DBO.GetCheckConstraints_Dup", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tableName;

                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        constraints.Add(new Constraints() { FieldName = dataReader["column_name"].ToString(), Constraint = ConstraintType.Check, ConstraintValue = dataReader["constraint_value"].ToString() });

                    }
                }
            }

            return constraints;
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you are connecting to the wrong database and as a result the result set is empty as the table `Customer` doesn't exist?

Comment: No I am connecting the correct database, I could see the value for the column_name column. Only the definition column is coming as empty.

Comment: Please post the DDL of the Customer table a simple but complete listing of the ADO.NET code you are using.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, added the detailed scripts and ado.net code

Answer (score 0):

No repro for me.  Does this repro?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp18
    {
        class Program
        {

            static string ddl = @"
    GO

    --if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'Customer')
   -- begin
    --    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
    --    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
    --    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_601769201]
    --end

    go
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 7/10/2019 3:24:22 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CompanyId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [Prefix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
        [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [MiddleName] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Suffix] [varchar](4) NULL,
        [NickName] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [ProfilePictureName] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Company] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
        [DateOfDeath] [date] NULL,
        [Gender] [char](1) NOT NULL,
        [Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [IsActive] [char](1) NULL,
        [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [UpdatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [Process] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [MessageId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [SysStartDate] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
        [SysEndDate] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC,
        [CompanyId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartDate], [SysEndDate])
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    WITH
    (
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_601769201] )
    )
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [IsActive]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_PREFIX_CHECK] CHECK  (([Prefix]='Dr' OR [Prefix]='Miss' OR [Prefix]='Ms' OR [Prefix]='Mrs' OR [Prefix]='Mr'))
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_PREFIX_CHECK]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_SUFFIX_CHECK] CHECK  (([Suffix]='RN' OR [Suffix]='MD' OR [Suffix]='ESQ' OR [Suffix]='DO' OR [Suffix]='DDS' OR [Suffix]='DDM' OR [Suffix]='III' OR [Suffix]='II' OR [Suffix]='I' OR [Suffix]='Sr' OR [Suffix]='Jr'))
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_SUFFIX_CHECK]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_TYPE_CHECK] CHECK  (([Type]='Customer' OR [Type]='VENDOR' OR [Type]='INSIDER' OR [Type]='ANALYST' OR [Type]='INVESTOR'))
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_TYPE_CHECK]
    GO




    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCheckConstraints_Dup](@tableName as varchar(200))
    AS
    BEGIN
    select 
        col.[name] as column_name,
        con.[definition] As [constraint_value]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    where t.[name]=@tableName and con.is_disabled=0
    order by con.name;
    End;

    GO
    ";
            static IEnumerable<string> GetBatches(string script)
            {
                var rdr = new System.IO.StringReader(script);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (true)
                {
                    var l = rdr.ReadLine()?.Trim();
                    if (l == null)
                    {
                        var batch = sb.ToString().Trim();
                        if (batch.Length > 0)
                            yield return sb.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (l.Equals( "GO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {

                        var batch = sb.ToString().Trim();
                        if (batch.Length > 0)
                            yield return sb.ToString();
                        sb.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(l.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var constr = "Server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true";

                using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    foreach (var batch in GetBatches(ddl))
                    {

                        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = batch;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    var constraints = GetConstraints("Customer", constr);
                    foreach (var constraint in constraints)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{constraint.FieldName} {constraint.ConstraintValue}");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            public static List<Constraints> GetConstraints(string tableName, string connectionString)
            {
                var constraints = new List<Constraints>();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    //SqlDataReader
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DBO.GetCheckConstraints_Dup", connection);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tableName;

                    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {

                            constraints.Add(new Constraints() { FieldName = dataReader["column_name"].ToString(), Constraint = "Check", ConstraintValue = dataReader["constraint_value"].ToString() });

                        }
                    }
                }

                return constraints;
            }

            public class Constraints
            {
                public string FieldName { get; internal set; }
                public string Constraint { get; internal set; }
                public string ConstraintValue { get; internal set; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Every time I run, I am able to reproduce this. Not sure what a weird problem is this. I hard code some string instead of definition in sql statement and I get that back in datareader but when I put back definition field it always comes as empty :(

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I am using .net core 2.1. Can you try repo in core? I tried with Dapper also and returns null.

Comment: Still no repro.  .NET 4.7, .NET core 2.1, .NET Core 2.2

Comment: Thanks Davind!!!. I Found it, This is the problem with the application user I am trying to access the table. The DB user has the permission since it's using the NT authentication(owner).